# How do I have various pieces of information associated with one value in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

EDIT:  CHECK AT THE BOTTOM FOR A MORE CLEAR VIEW OF WHAT I AM DOING, PLEASE!

As an example, let's say I have information on three cars:

```
Car One
500hp
180mph
15mpg

Car Two
380hp
140mph
24mpg

Car Three
450hp
170mph
20mpg
```

I want to put that in a dictionary, or SOMETHING, so that I can easily access it through a function.

```
def fuel_eco(car):
   return("The fuel economy for %s is %s" % (car, mpg))
def top_speed(car):
   return("The top speed for %s is %s" % (car, speed))
def horsepower(car):
   return("The horsepower for %s is %s" % (car, hp))
```

Basically have a module with some functions and a list/dictionary/whatever of the information, and then have another script that asks what car they want to view info on, and what information they want to know.

```
import carstats

car = input("What car do you want to find out about?")
stat = input("What information do you want to know?")
getStat = getattr (carstats, stat)
print(getStat(car))
```

How do I store the information for the three vehicles (And more if I add them) in a dictionary, so I can retrieve the information?

---

Okay, these are the actual files I am working with:

File one is asoiaf.py:

```
def sigil (house):
 """
 Function to return a description of the sigil of a specified Great House.
 Takes one argument, the name of the House.
 """
 house = house.lower ()
 if house == "stark":
  sigil = "a grey direwolf on a white field."
 elif house == "lannister":
  sigil = "a golden lion rampant on a crimson field."
 elif house == "targaryen":
  sigil = "a red three-headed dragon on a black field."
 else:
  sigil = "Unknown"
 house = str(house[0].upper()) + str(house[1:len(house)])
 return("The sigil for House %s is %s" % (house, sigil))


def motto (house):
 """
 Function to return the family motto of a specified Great House.
 Takes one argument, the name of the House.
 """
 house = house.lower ()
 if house == "stark":
  motto = "Winter is coming!"
 elif house == "lannister":
  motto = "Hear me roar!"
 elif house == "targaryen":
  motto = "Fire and blood!"
 else:
  motto = "Unknown"
 house = str(house[0].upper()) + str(house[1:len(house)])
 return("The motto for House %s is:  %s" % (house, motto))
```

The second file is encyclopedia.py:

```
import asoiaf
#import sl4a

#droid = sl4a.Android ()
#sound = input ("Would you like to turn on sound?")
info = "yes"

while info == "yes":
 #if sound == "yes":
 # droid.ttsSpeak ("What house do you want to learn about?")
 house = input ("What house do you want to learn about?")
 house = str(house[0].upper()) + str(house[1:len(house)])
 #if sound == "yes":
 # droid.ttsSpeak  ("What do you want to know about House %s?" % house)
 area = input ("What do you want to know about House %s?" % house)
 getArea = getattr (asoiaf, area)
 #if sound == "yes":
 # droid.ttsSpeak (getArea (house))
 print (getArea (house))
 #if sound == "yes":
 # droid.ttsSpeak  ("Would you like to continue learning?")
 info = input ("Would you like to continue learning?")
 if info == "no":
  print ("Goodbye!")
```

You'll see a lot of commenting out in the last code, because I had to comment out the TTS that I have for my phone, since most people are not on an Android right now.  As you can see, I am using IF, ELIF, ELSE in the functions, and I am just trying to see if there is an easier way.  I apologize if it is/was confusing.

Comment: I would look at making a class for your car. You can make those functions part of that class. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: Make a dictionary of lists/dictionaries/`namedtuple`s/classes?

Comment: I've read over the classes page, and one of the things looked similar to what I need in STORING the information, but the problem with the Python docs is that they assume a STRONG understanding already.  I am having trouble connecting the creation of a set of data (Such as in section 9.7) with how to actually get the information later.

Comment: @Ernesto Here is the python class magic. Once you have created your object and stored some data in it., you can access them again in the same way! let's say you have done `my_car.speed = 100`, then you can always later, reuse this data, by doing `some_stuff = 10*my_car.speed + 5`. Python will look for a speed attribute in the my_car var, and simply get that value.

Comment: Would be nice if people would comment instead of assigning negatives.  I am trying to answer any questions and update with any relevant information.  If you think the question is poorly worded, let me know, don't just neg it.

Comment: "Is there a better way" is the type of question that is out of scope at Stack Overflow, and gets questions closed and possibly deleted.   The downvotes likely reflect that 1) You have asked too broad of a question and 2) you have cluttered your question with lots of irrelevant information.   Your question was better before you added all the extra stuff.

Comment: I don't think my question was "better" because I wasn't getting the answers I needed.  The commenting system on this website is a goddamn joke, without "answering" my own question or updating the question, I cannot post a full bit of code in the comments.  To clarify what I meant, I had to update the original question.

That doesn't change the fact that if people think the question is too broad and should be clarified or removed, they should either post and ask me to clarify, or flag and have it closed/removed.

Comment: ADDITIONALLY:
http://stackoverflow.com/tour

If you read that page, it does not say that asking for a better way to do something is out of the scope of this website.

Ask about...

Specific programming problems
Software algorithms
Coding techniques
Software development tools

Don't ask about...

Questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)
Product or service recommendations or comparisons
Requests for lists of things, polls, opinions, discussions, etc.
Anything not directly related to writing computer programs

Comment: Clearly, my question was about a specific programming problem and coding techniques.  It did not meet any of the "Don't ask about" criteria.  I showed my work, it has nothing to do with product/service recommendations, didn't ask for a list of things or anything other than how to do something, and it was CLEARLY related to writing computer programs...

Comment: Both the quality answers to your question were supplied before you extended it with the extraneous material.    Some of the interpretations of the guidelines for StackOverflow surprise new users.    That doesn't mean that they are wrong: they are the rules that have made it work as well as it does.

Comment: I appreciate that you went to some effort to meet the guidelines, but you missed a number of points.  1) Questions can't be opinion based.  This means "what is a better way to" is simply not allowed.  2) Questions can't be too broad.  "They should be able to be answered in a couple of paragraphs".  3) They should be considerate of the answerers.     http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  4) One question per question, with a meaningful title.  The question you ask should be the one you asked in the title.    meta.stackexchange.com has answers about why the commenting system is the way it is.

Comment: While both "answers" were given before the last update, the one that was ultimately chosen as the best answer (Creating a Class) was not actually answering the question.  It was only answering half the question.  Unless you want me to have a 500 character title question, any intelligent person expects the main title to not have all the information.  That's why there is BODY of the question, so you can clarify and add additional information to the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a class should be the best way to do it:

```
class Car: # define the class

    def __init__(self, name, speed, hp, mpg):
        # This is the constructor. The self parameter is handled by python,
        # You have to put it. it represents the object itself
        self.name = name
        self.speed = speed
        self.hp = hp
        self.mpg = hp
        # This bind the parameters to the object
        # So you can access them throught the object
```

You can then use the object this way:

```
my_car1 = Car('Car One', 180, 500, 15)
my_car1.speed # Will return 180
```

Concercing the `__init__` name, it has to be this name, all constructors have this name (that's how Python know it is the class constructor). The `__init__` method is called when you call `Car('car one', 180, 500, 15)`. You have to ommit the self parameter, Python handle it.
You can add other function to your class, like

```
def top_speed(self):
    return 'The top speed is {}'.format(self.speed)
```

Then you simply have to do my_car1.topspeed()
In every function you define in a class self must be the first parameter (except some rare cases such as classmethod or staticmethods). Obviously the topseed function works only if you create it in the `class Car:` block.

I'd suggest you should read more about object oriented programming (OOP) in Python. Just google OOP python and you will have a lot of serious ressources explaining you how to create classes and how to use them.

This [official python classes tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/classes.html) should help you a lot in understanding the concept.

EDIT:

Regarding the accessing of the class in an other script. It's simple:

let's say you save the code above in a car.py file. Just place that file in the same folder as your other script, and in your other script do:

```
from car import Car # car is the name of the .py file, Car is the class you want to import
name = input('Car name: ')
speed = int(input('Car speed: ')) # input return a string, you have to cast to an integer to have a number
hp = int(input('Car hp: '))
mpg = int(input('Car mpg : '))
my_car = Car(name,speed,hp,mpg) # Then you just create a Car Object with the data you fetched from a user.
stuff = my_car.speed * my_car.hp # An example of how to use your class
print('The given car have {} mph top speed and have {} horsepower'.format(my_car.speed,my_car.hp))
```

What you have to understand is that a Class is some kind of a formated data type. When creating a Car class, you are defining how to create a car object. And Each time you call Car(...), you actually create one of these object, the value you put in the object are whatever values you want to put. It could be random number, user input or even network fetched data. You can use this object as you want.

Edit 2:

Given your code. Creating classes will change some things. Let's Give an example.

File 1 houses.py:

```
class House: # defining a house class
    def __init__(self,name, sigil, motto):
        self.name = name
        self.sigil = sigil
        self.moto = motto

 # Then, in the same file, you create your houses.
 starks =  House('starks','grey direwolf on a white field','Winter is coming!')
 lannisters = House('lannisters', 'a golden lion rampant on a crimson field', 'Hear me roar!')
 # let's skip targaryen, it's the same way...
 unknown_house = House('unknown','unknown','unknow')
 houses = [starks, lannisters]
 def get_house(name):
     for house in houses:
         if house.name == name:
             return house
     return unknow_house # if no house match, return unknow
```

Then in your second file. You just se that:

```
import houses
house_wanted = input('What house do you want to know about?')
my_house = houses.get_house(house_wanted)
print('this is the house {}; Sigil {} and motto {}'.format(my_house.name, my_house.sigil, my_house.motto))
```

If you plan on working on biggers set. You should have a look at Enums. That could fit what you want.

If you want to getting a precise attribute, you can do it this way:

```
import houses
house_wanted = input('What house do you want to know about?')
my_house = houses.get_house(house_wanted)
attr= input('What do you want to know about that house?')
print(getattr(my_house,attr.lower()))
```

Note this last thing will raise an error if you call for non-existent attr (like foo).

Comment: @Ernesto I have added the way to create a car from a separate script

Comment: @Ernesto I have added an example of object model in your case.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bgU1jvSC

That is what I have done so far.  Seems to work great, although if I type in the name of an attribute wrong it'll whine at me and force me to restart the  script.

Comment: @Ernesto You can then check for error by encapsulating your code in a Try/except structure. http://pastebin.com/4iRt7Hve. If you place this inside your main loop, you can ask for wrong attribute as much as you want, Without stopping the script or breaking the loop

Comment: Thanks, I knew there was an option for that, I couldn't remember how it was done.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve the broader problem you describe in the text of your question (the question of how to store multiple pieces of information about an object).   Classes maybe one good one.   Classes have the advantage of better robustness than dictionaries.

To answer the specific question in the summary/title: "how to have more than one item associated with one key in a dictionary" - use dictionaries as the values, like this:

```
car_info = {'CarOne': {'power': 500, 'speed': 180, 'mileage': 18},
            'CarTwo': {'power': 380, 'spead': 200, 'mileage': 10}
            }

print "Car Two has power %d mileage %d" % (car_info['CarTwo']['power'], car_info['CarTwo']['mileage'])
```

You can see that this is not especially robust by trying to access the 'speed' for "CarTwo".  If you look closely you will see that because I made a deliberate typo in the initializer for CarTwo, it does not have a speed at all, it has a spead.   Classes will catch this error, dictionaries will not.

This is not a reason not to do it with dictionaries - just something to be aware of when deciding for your particular case.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class, called car, with whatever attributes you want!
Here's a great tutorial on how to do that: [class tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm)
I'm on the road right now, but if you're having trouble, please tell me so that I can write some useful code...